# Serialize and deserialize multiple custom objects to XML

Tags: c#, serialization

I have to serialize multiple custom objects like Customer, Store, etc. Each object has just properties, and objects no relationship with each other. I have to serialize to XML, and deserialize back to custom objects.

How can I do this in C# ?

Answer (score 1):

Generate the xsd as follows:

```
 "$(Registry:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\@InstallationFolder)\bin\xsd.exe" /n:"$(ProjectName).Namespace" "$(ProjectDir)\<YourXML>"
```

This should be a 1 times thing since your validation will stay constant.

create a prebuild event in your project for generating the class as follows:

```
<PreBuildEvent>
  "$(Registry:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\@InstallationFolder)\bin\xsd.exe" /n:"$(ProjectName).Namespace" "$(ProjectDir)\<YourXSD>" /c /o:"$(ProjectDir)\<GeneratedClassFolder>"
</PreBuildEvent>
```

Then you can use the built in .NET XMLSerializer to write your classes to an XML file.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an `XSD` file defining your classes.  Then you can use the built in .NET [XMLSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) to write your classes to an XML file.  You can use the XSD to validate your inputs during deserialization.

Or you can apply the [Serializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx) attribute for your classes.

Comment: you can do this without an XSD

Answer (score 0):

a quick google reveals [this article](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-xml-serialization) on Switch On The code with examples on how to serialize and deserialize to XML.  here is an code example on serializing and deserializing an object.

```
static public void SerializeToXML<_type>(_type item,string fileName)
{
  XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer( item.GetType() );
  TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter( fileName );
  serializer.Serialize(textWriter, item);
  textWriter.Close();
}

static _type DeserializeFromXML<_type>(string fileName)
{
   XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(_type));
   TextReader textReader = new StreamReader( fileName );

   _type item = (_type)deserializer.Deserialize(textReader);
   textReader.Close();

   return item;
}
```

Comment: yup, you may want to look at this msdn article on how to get more control over the serialization: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z(v=vs.80).aspx